# Framed minipage of dependent dimensions

Tags: framed, minipage

I am trying to prepare handouts of a ppt (I know). I would like a slide to be shown on the left half of a page and comments regarding it in a framed box of the same size as the slide on the right half. By

```
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[page=4,scale=.3]{my_ppt}
\end{minipage}
```

I can get the slide in, but how do I create a minipage to the right of it that has the same height as the previous minipage?

Is minipage the environment of choice here? And is the framed package the best way to get a frame around it?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense putting a `\includgraphics` into a `minipage`. Also I would use `width` and/or `height` not `scale` to determine the size. You can put the image into a savebox and measure its size. Which class and layout do you like to use for this document?

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper]{report}, right using the minipage here is not that useful, I just thought it might be possible crating an empty copy of it to the right somehow. How do I do this with the savebox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An environment form can be obtained as follows

```
\newsavebox\pptbox
\newenvironment{pptcomment}[2][]
  {\sbox\pptbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
   \dimen0=\ht\pptbox
   \parbox{.5\textwidth}{\centering\usebox\pptbox}%
   \begin{lrbox}{\pptbox}\begin{minipage}[c][\dimexpr\dimen0-2\fboxsep\relax][c]
     {\dimexpr.5\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}}
  {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}\fbox{\box\pptbox}}
```

and then used as

```
\begin{pptcomment}[page=4,scale=.3]{my_ppt}
The comment text that will be vertically centered
with respect to the image on its left
\end{pptcomment}
```

In other words, you pass the new environment the same parameters you'd pass to `\includegraphics`. However, setting `scale` is not recommended.

How does this work?

We allocate a new bin `\pptbox` for storing objects; the first use of it is for measuring the height of the image (`\ht\pptbox`, which is stored in the temporary dimension register `\dimen0`). Then we typeset the image in a `\parbox` so that it will be vertically centered with respect to other objects. Next we open `lrbox`, which is the "environment form of `\mbox`, storing the contents again in the `\pptbox` bin. This box consists of a `minipage` vertically centered (`[c]`), as high as `\dimen0` (i.e., the height of the image) minus twice the clearance between a box and the frame (`\fboxsep`); the contents of this minipage will be centered with respect to the total height; finally the `minipage` will be as wide as half the textwidth. The contents of the environment is read in and then the bin is wrapped up (`\end{lrbox}`) and used inside `\fbox`.

It's best to use `pptcomment` inside a `center` environment, which can also be inserted directly in the environment:

```
\newsavebox\pptbox
\newenvironment{pptcomment}[2][]
  {\begin{center}
   \sbox\pptbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
   \dimen0=\ht\pptbox
   \parbox{.5\textwidth}{\centering\usebox\pptbox}%
   \begin{lrbox}{\pptbox}\begin{minipage}[c][\dimexpr\dimen0-2\fboxsep\relax][c]
     {\dimexpr.5\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}}
  {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}\fbox{\box\pptbox}
   \end{center}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is really nice! Could you for a novice as me comment a bit on what exactly is going on in your environment definition? Also is the slide indented, which, when making it .5\textwidth wide, results in the comment hanging over into the right side margin. Is there a work around?

Comment: @user7091 Such an environment should be set inside a `center` environment. I'll add some explanations later.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't make much sense putting a `\includgraphics` into a `minipage`. Also I would use `width` and/or `height` not `scale` to determine the size. You can put the image into a savebox and measure its size.

Something along the lines of:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox\mysavebox

\begin{document}

\sbox\mysavebox{\includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{image}}
\usebox\mysavebox\hfill
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[b][\ht\mysavebox][t]{.49\textwidth}%
your text
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

This however makes the framed `minipage` have a depth of `\fboxsep` which you can correct using e.g. `\raisebox{\fboxsep}{..}`. Using the `adjustbox` package would simplify these combinations:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newsavebox\mysavebox

\begin{document}

\sbox\mysavebox{\includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{image}}
\usebox\mysavebox\hfill
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[b][\ht\mysavebox-2\fboxsep][t]{.49\textwidth},fbox,raise=\fboxsep}%
your text your text your text your text your text your text your text your text your text your text
your text your text your text your text your text your text your text your text your text your text
your text your text your text your text your text your text your text your text your text your text
your text your text your text your text your text your text your text your text your text your text
your text your text your text your text your text your text your text your text your text your text
your text your text your text your text your text
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

I added a tight frame around the image so the correct size and alignment can be shown. Simply remove it later.

[image: Result]